# i want connect my office 365 mail with ci but this not connect

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, office365

i want connect my office 365 mail with ci but this not connect i use namecheap server office 365 from godaddy

````
require('/home/shoodkoi/public_html/emailcampaign/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port= 587;
$mail->Username='';
$mail->Password= '';
$mail->Host= "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@gbosss.co.in', 'Gbosss');```
````

Answer (score 0):

Missing username & password

```
$mail->Username='';
$mail->Password= '';
```

Also to note that the FROM address must be the same as smtp_user